# Camera 2D coords from 3D object coords

Tags: camera, geometry, projection

I am working on a geometry editor tool and I am dealing with the way how to get manipulators vector coordinates on the screen/camera plane so I can use these for mouse dragging. I've got access to vectors world coordinates matrix (or any objects matrix), projection matrix and camera direction, position etc.

Comment: Multiply the world coordinates by the view-projection matrix, do a perspective divide, and you have your coordinates in clip space. Look for one of the many tutorials about this.

Comment: thank you, I was searching for it and non of the results were helpful. Or am I just dumb? nevermind, thx a lot!